# Two different sequences that are subsequence of each other.

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for two sequences $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}  ,(b_n)_{n \ge 0}$ that are not the same sequences but such that each is a subsequence of each other?

My confusion part is about showing that they are subsequences of each other? Can anyone help me with this ? Thank you

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax references.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Consider $$a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & ,n \text{ is even} \\ 0 & ,n \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

Try to construct a similar sequence $b_n$.